# Problema con fecha en consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema con una fecha rebelde. resulta que tengo que hacer una consulta entre dos fechas, que seria esta:

```
SELECT id FROM `Pedidos` WHERE (`fecha_cobro` BETWEEN '$fechini' AND '$fechafin') AND borrado = 0
```

Vengo de un formulario que en el que selecciono las fechas que quiero que aparezcan en la búsqueda. Y convierto la fecha de formato español a americano para que mysql las entienda y lo hago asi:

```
$fechini=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["Listado_fechaini"]));
$fechafin=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["Listado_fechafin"]));
```

Pero resulta que $fechafin tiene vida propia y solo funciona en determinados casos, por ejemplo si pongo 01/01/2018, pero si pongo la fecha de hoy dice que tu tia. he probado a ponerle comillas simples, comillas dobles, comillas mágicas, llamar a uno de comillas a ver si sabe algo. Pero nada no consigo ver el error.
en cambio si pongo directamente la fecha en la consulta funciona siempre, asi que deduzco que el fallo esta en fechafin.

Por otro lado he probado a mostrar que trae ese post por si el fallo estaba en el formulario, pero no, trae la fecha correcta ( en formato español ).

A parte de ir a tirarle un zapato a Rajoy ¿que se os ocurre que podría hacer?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: hola @Marc pero el formato que le estoy dando a la fecha si no me equivoco es 2017-12-01. el caso es que si muestro la fecha que me convierte fechafin en la mayoria de los casos es 1970

Comment: Si, lo que viene es dd/mm/yyyy @Marc

Comment: Ahora si :) Mil gracias @Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buenas Killpe,

El problema es que un formato usa un separador (`Formato español '/'`) y el otro usa uno diferente (`Formato inglés '-'`).

Debes poner un replace para los separadores para poder castear bien la fecha, de la siguiente forma:

```
$fechafin=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$_POST["Listado_fechafin"])));
```